# Get the IDE to dynamically refer to the constructor when calling a static method

Tags: php

Let's say i have a parent and a child class like that:

```php
class Component {

    public function __construct(string $string)
    {
        //...
    }

}

class ChildComponent  extends Component {

    public function __construct(string $string, array $args)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Now I would like to implement a static method to instantiate classes, like that:

```php
class Component {

    public function __construct(string $string)
    {
        //...
    }

    public static function create(...$args): static
    {
        return new static(...$args);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to have the IDE suggest the expected arguments of the static::class (even if only the constructor annotations), maybe with PHP 8 attributes ? This is what I would like to have:

```php
Component::create() // IDE refers to the constructor of "Component" ($string expected)
ChildComponent::create() // IDE refers to the constructor of "child component" ($string and $array expected)
```

Please avoid"

> why would you do that anyway ...

or

> Just define the "static create" on each child

Edit: "new" method renamed "create" for clarity purposes

Comment: What do the parent and child classes have to do with referring to the `static` class?

Comment: What I meant to say, is that the IDE knows the context, and refers to the statically called class constructor, instead of the "new" from the parent class.

Comment: Oops, I didn't realize `new static()` is a special case, not creating an instance of a class named `static`.